# Replace element if its in viewport for x seconds

Tags: javascript

Hello currently im using this code, to check if element is in viewport and then replacing it with something else. Anyone have any ideas how can I make it to replace element only if its in viewport for, by example atleast 2 seconds?

```
var test = {
    elementViewportChecker: function(el) {
        var rect = el.getBoundingClientRect(),
            top = rect.top,
            height = rect.height,
            el = el.parentNode;

        do {
            rect = el.getBoundingClientRect();
            if(top <= rect.bottom === false)
                return false;

            if((top + height) <= rect.top)
                return false;

            el = el.parentNode;
        } while(el != document.body);

        return top <= document.documentElement.clientHeight;
    },
    isElementIntoView: function(el) {
        return this.elementViewportChecker(el);
    },
};

if(test.isElementIntoView(element)) {
   element.doSomething();
}
```

I've tried multiple ways, but none of them worked. I would really a appreciate if someone could help me with this.

Comment: Please show what you have tried; someone might be able to help fix it.

Comment: @ScottHunter I tried with setTimeout and few other variations, but then I realized that it's stupid and it wont work

Comment: Please *show* what you have tried; someone might be able to help fix it.